# Interactive regression results

Tags: python, interface, interactive

I'm coding a recursive feature selection in Python, where I'm selecting most significant predictor variables based on some criterion. I'm making a loop and displaying features over each iteration, and a table of statistics summary of every regression. I would like to display update the table values every iteration in a graphical interface, does anyone know what package should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In terms of graphical interface to use, I would definitely recommend using PYSimpleGUI (https://pypi.org/project/PySimpleGUI/) especially since you want to update values per iteration.

Its an easy to use, flexible GUI, and PySimpleGUI is released on PyPI as 5 distinct packages.

- PySimpleGUI - tkinter version 2.
- PySimpleGUI27 - tkinter version that runs on 2.7 3.
- PySimpleGUIWx - WxPython version 4.
- PySimpleGUIQt - PySided2 version 5.
- PySimpleGUIWeb - The web (Remi) version

Here's a link to the Table Element with all its methods etc. (https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#table-element)